# OutputDataReceived no real time output

Tags: c#

hii i am working with cmd and cmd take minimum 10 second to finish all the job.
and cmd throw new line approx every second,i want to read that line at same time.
But i dont have idea whats wrong in my code,its throw all the cmd lines in onces after process finish.
I hope someone will help me to get out of this prob. :)
//method

```
private void readBack()
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "XXXX.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "XXXXXXX";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            //process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

//output data

```
private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.data))
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Action action = () => richTextBox1.AppendText(e.data + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.Invoke(action);
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(e.data + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        }
```

// btn code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bW = new BackgroundWorker();
        bW.DoWork += (s, eb) =>
            {
                readBack();
            };
        bW.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: This is normal, most programs that detect their output being redirected will switch to buffered output.  Which greatly improves throughput.  You only get something when the buffer fills to capacity or is flushed explicitly.  The latter normally only happens when the program terminates.  So you get everything in one whack.  Fixing that requires changes in the program, it has to explicitly flush the output buffer.  That's usually where it ends.

Comment: sorry as i am new to this,you mean i cannot fix it ?